# What is a software or app that extracts old flip phone data to a Mac via USB?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, storage, data-recovery, file-transfer

UPDATE, here is how I got the [photos out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214306/155358).

---

I'm looking for a software, preferably free, that can extract old flip phone data to a MacBook Pro. I have some photos and sound recording saved on my Samsung AT&T SGH-a687 phone with a broken gpu (so I can't see anything). These are not saved on the SD card. 
[The manual](https://www.att.com/support_static_files/manuals/Samsung_Strive_A687.pdf) of the phone doesn't seem to have an option to transfer photos and sounds out. So I would like to have a software that can extract all those phone data for me via USB onto my computer.

I tried downloading a trial version of [DataPilot](http://download.cnet.com/DataPilot/3000-18511_4-144189.html), but that appeared to just be an updater, not the actual DataPilot. (I also hope it isn't a malware.)

If there is nothing free, what are the software you'd recommend me using? I'm willing to pay up to around $50.

Btw, I have a backup PC, if there's an extraction software for a PC, that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried contacting any local stores your phone provider has? It's becoming less common nowadays as basic phones are no longer the norm but back in the day they had a machine they could connect your phone to and transfer information out of it then on to a different phone.

Maybe you could call around to local stores and see if any of them still have such machine.

Otherwise, I did a bit of research because I used to know of some software that was for advanced phone modification before smartphones came around however it had a small feature to also see saved files.

I can't seem to find the software I remember using anymore, however I did find [BitPim](http://www.bitpim.org/):

> BitPim is a program that allows you to view and manipulate data on many CDMA phones from LG, Samsung, Sanyo and other manufacturers. This includes the PhoneBook, Calendar, WallPapers, RingTones (functionality varies by phone) and the Filesystem for most Qualcomm CDMA chipset based phones. To see when phones will be supported, which ones are already supported and which features are supported, see online help.
>
> http://www.bitpim.org/

It seems very similar to the software I used to use, however I've never used it before so I can not offer any help with it other than [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD88hOiCJNU) I found.

Comment: Hi herculeesjr, would BitPim work for AT&T which is not a CDMA phone?

Comment: Ah my apologies I did not see that it was for CDMA only, it does not look like it supports non-CDMA phones unfortunately.

Comment: "Maybe you could call around to local stores and see if any of them still have such machine. " Thanks for giving this suggestion. In my update to my question, that is in fact how I got the photos out!