# Old phone cannot connect to computer, the "computer connection" icon appears on phone

Tags: macbook-pro, network, photos, data-transfer, data-recovery

I would like to get some pictures and audio out of an AT&T SGH-a687 phone onto my Mac computer. I first tried connecting it to a New PC Studio on a PC, but there was a problem after transfer 2 photos, so I tried again. But the PC could no longer detect the phone, even though the "connected to computer" icon appears on the phone. I tried a different cable, different USB ports. No use.

So I downloaded the Samsung Kies on my Mac. Same thing, it tries to search for the phone once I connect the phone, but the computer doesn't detect anything. The phone still shows the "connected to computer" icon.

There is also Bluetooth (no internet on the phone) on the phone, but it failed to send the picture each time I tried.

What can I do at this point? Please also suggest data extraction software for either Mac or PC, if that's the easier route.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I finally got the photos.

I called various cell phone stores and asked for if they have a Cellebrite machine, a phone forensics machine that can get out contacts, pictures, and videos out. An AT&T store has it. So I went there.

The machine failed to connect to read from the phone twice, but it worked the 3rd time!! I got most of my pictures out. A read failure occurred twice during the transfer. Once I hit "retry" and it continued to work. The second time, it actually stopped. But I got the important photos out and I was so happy!

I transferred the photos to my iPad. But You can transfer it to another phone. I tried transferring to my USB drive, but a read failure occurred as well around half way. After I checked the USB drive, it didn't have any pictures on it. So be careful if you choose that option.

Btw, I don't know why the machine couldn't get my audio out. But those were not important. So I don't care.